# Массив PictureBox

Tags: c#, winforms, form

Делаю форму в которой можно было бы переворачивать изображения, которые находятся в табконроле.
Мне кажется, что проблема в массиве `PictureBox`.

[image: Скрин формы]

```
 using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Text;
 using System.Windows.Forms;
using MetroFramework.Components;
using MetroFramework.Forms;

namespace Image
{
public partial class MainForm : MetroForm
{
    Rectangle screenSize = System.Windows.Forms.Screen.PrimaryScreen.Bounds;
    int logoOffset;
    int index;
    PictureBox[] ArrayofIMG;
    Bitmap temp;
    public MainForm()
    {

            InitializeComponent();

            ArrayofIMG = new PictureBox[TabCTRL.TabPages.Count];
            for (int i = 0; i < (int)TabCTRL.TabPages.Count; i++)
            {
                PictureBox a = new PictureBox();
                ArrayofIMG[i] = a;

                Controls.Add(a);               
            }
         logoOffset = this.Width - logo.Width;
        this.StyleManager = msmMain;



    }

    private void MainForm_Resize(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        logo.Width = this.Width - logoOffset;

    }

    private void left_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
         index = TabCTRL.SelectedIndex;
        rotate("left",index);

    }

    private void right_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        index = TabCTRL.SelectedIndex;
        rotate("right",index);
    }

    void rotate(string side, int index)
    {


        if (ArrayofIMG[index].Image != null)
        {
            temp = new Bitmap(ArrayofIMG[index].Image);
            ArrayofIMG[index].Image.Dispose();
            switch (side)
            {
                case "left":
                    temp.RotateFlip(RotateFlipType.Rotate270FlipNone);
                    break;
                case "right":
                    temp.RotateFlip(RotateFlipType.Rotate90FlipNone);
                    break;
            }
            ArrayofIMG[index].Image = temp;
            temp = null;
        }
    }

}
}
```

Comment: И какая проблема?

Comment: Соответственно, переворот не работает. Имена изображений pictureBox1... и т.д. Когда объявляешь массив, он же такие присваивает элементам?